# Generating Functional for Massless Spin 2 Particle

Tags: general-relativity, quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, path-integral, quantum-gravity

I'm trying to derive the generating functional for a massless, spin 2 field. However, I am getting a left over term that needs to go away. I'm working in de Donder gauge so that $\partial_\mu h^{\mu\nu}=\frac{1}{2}\partial_{\nu}h$. Here is what I've done

$$Z_0[T]=\int D[h]\  e^{i\int d^4x\ \mathcal{L_{EH}}+T^{\mu\nu}h_{\mu\nu}}.$$

Using the linearize Einstein-Hilbert action, we get

$$S=\int d^4x\ \mathcal{L_{EH}}+T^{\mu\nu}h_{\mu\nu}
        =\int d^4x\ \frac{-1}{4}h\Box h+\frac{1}{2}h^{\mu\nu}\Box h_{\mu\nu}+T^{\mu\nu}h_{\mu\nu}.$$

Fourier Transforming gives:

$$S=\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{d^4k}{(2\pi)^4}\frac{-k^2}{2}h_{\mu\nu}[-k]  (\eta^{\mu\gamma}\eta^{\nu\delta}+\eta^{\mu\delta}\eta^{\nu\gamma}-\eta^{\mu\nu}\eta^{\gamma\delta}) h_{\gamma\delta}[k]+T^{\mu\nu}[-k]h_{\mu\nu}[k]+T^{\mu\nu}[k]h_{\mu\nu}[-k].$$

Which we can write using $P^{\mu\nu\gamma\delta}=\frac{(\eta^{\mu\gamma}\eta^{\nu\delta}+\eta^{\mu\delta}\eta^{\nu\gamma}-\eta^{\mu\nu}\eta^{\gamma\delta})}{2}$

$$S=\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{d^4k}{(2\pi)^4}h_{\mu\nu}[-k] (-k^2) P^{\mu\nu\gamma\delta} 
 h_{\gamma\delta}[k]+T^{\mu\nu}[-k]h_{\mu\nu}[k]+T^{\mu\nu}[k]h_{\mu\nu}[-k].$$

Allowing $h_{\mu\nu}[k]->h_{\mu\nu}[k]+\frac{1}{k^2}P_{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}T^{\alpha\beta}$ which is allowed because it leaves the path integral the same, we get

$$Z[T]=\int D[h] e^{\frac{i}{2}\int \frac{d^4k}{(2\pi)^4} h_{\mu\nu}[-k] P^{\mu\nu\alpha\beta} 
 (-k^2) h_{\alpha\beta}[k] + \frac{1}{2k^2} T_{\mu\nu}[-k]P^{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}T_{\alpha\beta}[k] + \frac{1}{2} h[-k]T[k]+\frac{1}{2} h[k]T[-k]}$$

Where $h, T$ are traces. The first term in the action can be absorbed into the normalization Z[0] and the second term clearly has the propagator built into it as we desire. However, the very last term prevents me from extracting the correct propagator unless it is zero. How do I make this term go away? Is there a mistake?